# What's the difference between: people in England, people of England and English people?

Tags: differences, prepositions, word-usage

- People **in** England clean glass with newspaper.
- People **of** England clean glass with newspaper.
- English people clean glass with newspaper.

I would like to know which one sounds most natural. I would also like to know the usage of "people of England."

Comment: "People *in* England" refers to anyone who happens to be in England at the time.  "People *of* England" refers to people who are citizens of England and are typically  still living there. And "English people" refers to those who are from England regardless of where they might be living currently.

Comment: Jim and banksiae, people are not citizens of England because, England is not a country on its own. It is one part of the UK so, people of England are actually British citizens.

Comment: @tchrist et al, I disagree that this question is about proofreading. The OP is not asking users to check or correct his writing.  On the contrary he is asking about *meaning* and more specifically, *usage* of the expression "people of England".

Answer (score 1):

***People in England*** refers to people living in that country.
***People of England*** refers to people *from* that country; typically they are citizens.
***English people*** refers to people whose nationality is English.

However, when referring to the population, it is best to use the definite article with the adjective.

1. The English (or English people) clean glass with newspaper
2. The English have tea at 4 o'clock
3. The English drive on the left

This does exclude somewhat the Scots, the Welsh and people living in Northern Ireland, all of whom belong to what is commonly known as the United Kingdom  or Britain. As a result, many prefer saying "**the British**".

Comment: Thank you very much but now I have another question.  Are the "citizens of England" different from the "people whose nationality is English?"

Comment: There is no such thing as a "citizen of England". You are normally granted citizenship of the **United Kingdom** if you were born in England, Scotland, Wales or Northern Ireland. In other words, you can be born English and be a citizen of the UK. If for whatever reason you chose to live abroad and became a citizen of a different country e.g., the USA; your English/British nationality status remains unchanged.

Comment: banksiae, it is worth remembering that England is one of multiple nations that together, are the UK. People can be English, but not English citizens. They are citizens of the UK.

Answer (score 0):

*People* is plural, so they "clean" glass, or possibly "cleanse" it, but they don't "cleans" it.  As far as your question, "People *of* England" implies citizenship, "People *in* England" just means anyone who happens to be physically there at a given point.  *English people* is closer in meaning to the former ("of") than the latter ("in").